# Run macro on change within target range | Change (ByVal Target As Range)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with the `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` event.

I wanted to run a macro if either on of cells `A1` or `A2` are changed.
So the target range is set to `[A1, A2]`

Then, if `A1` is changed, I want to clear `A2`, or the other way around (`A2` is changed: clear `A1`).

Now the problem:

If `A1` value is changed. the macro clears `A2`. That's seen as a change in `A2`, so it clears `A1`, which is a change, etc...

I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't see how I can have cell `A1` be changed without triggering the change macro if `A2` is being cleared.

Anyone who has experience in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by toggling events off and on, like the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:A2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Me.Range("A2").Clear
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        Me.Range("A1").Clear
    End If

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few edge cases here, around changing more than one cell eg via copy pasting a range (possibly include other cells too).

Here's a version thats more robust in those cases

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:A2"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Select Case rng.Address(0, 0)
        ' If both changed, what now? Default to clearing A2
        Case "A1", "A1:A2"
            If Not IsEmpty(Me.Cells(1, 1)) Then
                Me.Cells(2, 1).Clear
            End If
        Case "A2"
            If Not IsEmpty(Me.Cells(2, 1)) Then
                Me.Cells(1, 1).Clear
            End If
    End Select

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```